# Calculate p-value for difference between ICC values

Tags: r, p-value, intraclass-correlation, agreement-statistics

I cannot seem to find an answer to the following problem: I am doing interreader correlation studies where I calculate ICC values. It is quite easy to do this in R, but how do I calculate a p-value to see whether the interreader correlation of one group is better than the other group?

Comment: Nobody? I know that if the 95% CI of both ICCs don't overlap the p-value will be <0.05, but it should be possible to calculate an exact value?